# Delphi IDE freezes on code completion and jumping to declaration

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe8

*Okay, so this is not the best practice situation, but luckily I have an answer, so please bear with me.*

I'm working on a rather large Delphi project with lots of external APIs used. Those APIs are plugged in different ways, including units wrapped into IFDEFs in the DPR itself, when they are platform-dependent. Having IFDEFs in DPR is a bad practice - sure, but it is handy to have all the units listed in the project tree to switch between them (rather than switch between projects).

So I was adding another alternative API implementation to the project and as usual - wrapped the existing solution units into the `{$IFDEF SOME_API_DLL}` clause and a new solution units into another `{$IFDEF SOME_API_EXE}`.

Anyways, I noticed soon after, that the IDE started to freeze semi-randomly after just 3-5min of coding, which is unbearable toll.. The IDE would hog one CPU (e.g. 13% on 8-core PC). I was able to isolate the cause to be invocation of "autocomplete", "code completion" (Ctrl+Space) and "jump to declaration (Ctrl+Click).

The main question is - what could cause the IDE to freeze on how to resolve this?

I'm using Delphi XE8, but switching to other versions didn't help. Unfortunately newer 10.3+ versions (with claimed rewritten Code Insight) could not be tested/used due to third-party components.

Comment: Components for XE8 should work with newer/current Delphi versions, too, if you have the source code to recompile them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the bug being well connected to the new API implementation, I was able to track down the cause. So it appears that IDE does not like DPR files with IFDEFs (old news), but the real bummer seems to be that **IDE handles IFDEFs okay only if they wrap only one unit**.

The hint to the solution was the Project Tree, which gets auto-updated with units in DPR, but it auto-included only the first units after the IFDEF. Apparently, thats what also throws off the track the auto-completion.

Bad DPR structure that causes IDE to freeze on code-completion:

```
{$IFDEF EXTAI_API_DLL}
KM_ExtAI_DLL in 'src\KM_ExtAI_DLL.pas',
KM_ExtAI_DLLs in 'src\KM_ExtAI_DLLs.pas',
KM_ExtAI_SharedTypes in 'src\KM_ExtAI_SharedTypes.pas',
KM_ExtAI_SharedInterfaces in 'src\KM_ExtAI_SharedInterfaces.pas',
KM_ExtAIActions in 'src\KM_ExtAIActions.pas',
KM_ExtAIMaster in 'src\KM_ExtAIMaster.pas',
KM_ExtAIStates in 'src\KM_ExtAIStates.pas',
KM_ExtAIUtils in 'src\KM_ExtAIUtils.pas',
{$ENDIF}
```

Good DPR structure that lets IDE work well:

```
{$IFDEF EXTAI_API_DLL}KM_ExtAI_DLL in 'src\KM_ExtAI_DLL.pas',{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF EXTAI_API_DLL}KM_ExtAI_DLLs in 'src\KM_ExtAI_DLLs.pas',{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF EXTAI_API_DLL}KM_ExtAI_SharedTypes in 'src\KM_ExtAI_SharedTypes.pas',{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF EXTAI_API_DLL}KM_ExtAI_SharedInterfaces in 'src\KM_ExtAI_SharedInterfaces.pas',{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF EXTAI_API_DLL}KM_ExtAIActions in 'src\KM_ExtAIActions.pas',{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF EXTAI_API_DLL}KM_ExtAIMaster in 'src\KM_ExtAIMaster.pas',{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF EXTAI_API_DLL}KM_ExtAIStates in 'src\KM_ExtAIStates.pas',{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF EXTAI_API_DLL}KM_ExtAIUtils in 'src\KM_ExtAIUtils.pas',{$ENDIF}
```